# Is there a way to create an input parameter from an edit lighting page on a task?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Is there a way to make it so I can accept an input parameter on the edit lightning page for an LWC?
Example: If I place my LWC on a Task object. I want to get the record Id of two object fields that aren't part of the task object but live on the task page from related parent objects. So in the picture below I want both the Offer Id and the Launch Program but neither of them are the Task.WhatId
How Can I achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "I need to get this done ASAP" solution would be to assign the variable to the window element. The global "window" is available everywhere on the client and you can generally get away with it.

Why is this bad practice?
Because anyone can get away with it. It's easy to create an app with a team as little as three people to create a mass of spagetti code where one one knows where things are. The next developer coming along will want to use the record id somewhere else, and make their own window variable. You'll end up with NicksVariables, tomVars, etc all with duplicate properties. But I've personally used this when the client's pay is to low and I'm not responsible for the longevity of the project.

Best Practice?
Events up and Props down. You would need to find a common parent and propagate the record id up via a CustomEvent dispatch and consume it and pass it down as props to the component you need it in.

The Compromise.
I personally like using window event listeners to accomplish these tasks. It can be pretty tricky so I'd advise writing an internal API for dispatching and consuming to ensure you're not reusing event names. But simply put, you can dispatch CustomEvents to the window object and attach a window listener in the components you want to consume in. It can be as simple as:

```
function dispatch(event, data) {
  window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(event, { detail: data }));
}

function consume(event,callback) {
  window.addEventListener(event, callback);
}
```

You will need to remember to removeEventListener in your disconnectedCallback. You can also maintain a list of events in an array and if you dispatch multiple, you can throw an error if array.includes. The code example above is just a starting point. You can event have the consume return a removal function for that purpose:

```
function consume(event,callback) {
  window.addEventListener(event, callback);

  return () => window.removeEventListener(event, callback);
}
```

But I typically bake that into a custom LightningElement extended class that handles the disconnects for me.